# VS2010 Multi Project Templates

Tags: visual-studio-2010

trying to create a multiproject template. I have three projects in a multiproject template:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="ProjectGroup">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>ScratchPad Multiproject Template</Name>
    <Description>ScratchPad for quick C# development</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <Icon>__Icon.ico</Icon>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>ScratchPad</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="ScratchPad.ConsoleHost">ScratchPad.ConsoleHost\ScratchPad.ConsoleHost.csproj</ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="ScratchPad.Lib">ScratchPad.Lib\ScratchPad.Lib.csproj</ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="ScratchPad.Test">ScratchPad.Test\ScratchPad.Test.csproj</ProjectTemplateLink>  
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Then I make a zip file that consists of the above template, icon file and an unzipped folder for each individual project template. This zip I copy to ..\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates

All is well until I actually use the template with "New Project..." command. Then after I've selected the template and VS has asked me the target folder, it outputs following error:

[image]

If I see that project in the appdata folder, it's fine, it opens ok. Any ideas?

pom

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. In the templatecontent section one should not reference the csproj files but vstemplate files.